# easyui dialog allows background to b

Tags: dialog, modal-dialog, jquery-easyui

I am using a jeasyui dialog box which opens when clicked on a form button. But even when the dialog is open I am able to change the form behind. I want that when the dialog box is opened it should be closed first before anything else in the background becomes editable/ clickable.
How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your dialog set `modal:true` like this

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 550, 
    modal: true,
    hide: 'fade',
    show: 'fade',
    closeOnEscape: false, 
    draggable: true,
    resizable: true,
    title: 'My Dialog'
});
```